# Swift 2.0 animating images

Tags: swift2

Trying animate series of images in swift 2.0 but following the video tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSny6un3VUw the method that this guy uses are no longer relevant and swift 2.0 no longer allows arrays to be setup in such means. The basic code this guy used is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController: {
  @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView
  @IBOutlet var animationBtn: UIButton
  var imageList = UIImage[]() // no longer valid?

 @IBAction func animationBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
 startAnimation
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
for i in 1...13
{
let imageName = "\(1)"
imageList += UIImage(named: imageName) //line no longer works
}
}
func startAnimation() -> Void
{
 myImageView.animationImages = imageList
 myImageView.startAnimation()
 }
```

Anyone know a better way in swift 2.0 to animate images or anyway in general how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I will help you

```
@IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var animationBtn: UIButton!
```

`var imageList = [UIImage]()`

`imageList.append(UIImage(named: imageName))`
or
`imageList += [UIImage(named: imageName)]`

Comment: i tried the .append method myself but it didn't work so I will try the other suggestion you have

Comment: got the .append method to work finally it had something to do with the image files themselves actually not copying into the application for some reason....sorry